# Cannot install tensorflow with pip3, switches to python2

Tags: python3, pip

I am trying to install tensor flow using `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/index.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 6, in <module>
    import compileall
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The systems seems to be confusing the libraries of python3 and python2 when using pip3. The installation works for pyhton2 using `pip install tensorflow-gpu`.

**Edit 1**

I tried `python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu`, but the last library is still python2.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py
```

**Edit 2**

I tried this again and I found that because I have ROS installed it sets PYTHONPATH to python 2. So I had to modify the setup bash for ROS so PYTHONPATH is set by me and not ROS.

Comment: Pretty common for `pip3` to mess up and install into Python 2.7's directories. Try `python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu` and let me know if that helps.

Comment: The last two files are still Python 2 `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback`

Comment: I would try to use a `virtualenv -p python3` and have it all installed there, it's pretty easy to get pip all mangled between projects